# Why can I have only declarations in class scope?

Tags: ios, swift, oop

The compiler shows the Expected Declaration error:

```
for list in lists{
    let item = ChecklistItems()
    item.text = "Item for \(list.name))"
    list.items.append(item)
}
```

the code should be inside the body of any function of ViewController class. It can not be outside. But why? What is the real reason? unfortunately I didn't can find any docs that literally said this concept.

Comment: When would you expect that code to be executed if it is not inside a method of the class? – It is not allowed because it makes no sense.

Comment: When you writing ("declaring") functions, they not executed. You can execut it by calling function. Same for classes/structs/etc. But if you writing functional code outside of the function, when you expect it to be executed? You can do it in playgrounds - it is main purpose of them, but definitely it make no sense in iOS/MacOS app.  Try to google about app lifecycle, `main()` function

Comment: @ Martin R, thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have some "randomly" placed code. Even a set of instructions needs to be placed somewhere and referenced in ordered to be called later on. Otherwise you cannot use it, so hence the "Expected Declaration".

In every program you create, you have some generic stages along the lines of Preprocessed -> Compiled -> Assembled -> Linked

This flow basically transforms your code into something that can be used at a lower level for the system and basically use it (on the processor, memory.. ).

In order to "compile" your code and not get errors (like the Expected Declaration error) you need to have a common set of "transforming" rules and adjust to them. Otherwise, for example in your case the compiler will now know what to do with your code.